# Locating Historical records using Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select, plsql

I have the following Oracle employee table which tracks employee movement between various departments.

```
EMPID   DEPARTMENT  RECORD_DATE
123456  Technology  2019-01-01
123456  Technology  2019-02-25
123456  Finance     2019-03-01
123456  Finance     2019-09-28
123456  HR          2020-03-01

987654  HR          2019-04-01
987654  Finance     2019-09-01
987654  HR          2020-01-31
```

I need to write an Oracle PL/SQL script that will allow the user to define a department name, and a historical date, resulting in having the query display all employees that were assigned to that department at specific point in time.

Example: If I wanted to know all the employees that worked in Finance on 2019-10-01, the query would return:

```
EMPID   DEPARTMENT  DEPARTMENT_START_DATE  
123456  Finance     2019-03-01    
987654  Finance     2019-09-01
```

(Note, a Department "leave" date would be nice, but optional)

Any ideas?

Comment: Why PL/SQL - isn't a plain SQL `SELECT` statement enough? (Hint: a lot of uninformed people think "PL/SQL" means "Oracle SQL". It does not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions for this:

```
select empid, department, record_date
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        lead(record_date) over(partition by empid order by record_date) lead_record_date
    from mytable t
) t
where 
    department = :department_id
    and :target_date >= record_date 
    and (:target_date < lead_record_date or lead_record_date is null)
```

`:department_id` and `:target_date` represent the parameters to the query.

In the subquery, `lead()` retrieves the "next" `record_date` of the same `empid`. The outer query uses that information as a filter parameter to locate the relevant records.

Answer (score 0):

With your given example it seems ,you need employee list with historical date for each department(if worked).This can be achieved with simple subquery

```
select empid,record_date from(
select empid,department,record_Date,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by empid,department order by empid) as id
from employee)a
where id=1
order by 3
```